# How to install Windows after installing and deleting Linux

Tags: windows

After installing Linux Mint I formatted my HDD (using the bootable usb linux mint's partition manager Gparted) (ntfs formatted). The reason was that I want to install windows. I have my bootable windows usb which booted up fine before installing linux mint. The error that I get now is something like: SYSLINUX ....Copyright Peter...

So in other words, I can't get the windows installer to boot up after installing Linux Mint and after deleting it by formatting it to ntfs.

Comment: I think this belongs to SuperUser, but no migration close option to that site

Comment: Do you know how to oprn your BIOS setup utility?  F2, Del, etc... Also do you know if you have a UEFI Based computer or does it contain a Legacy BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are still booting from the hard drive and not starting the windows dvd. You have to change boot priority of the dvd drive (or usb drive in case you want to install from that) to be before the hard disk in the bios/uefi.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do a fresh install like normally, give priority to USB drive from BIOS or `<Quick Boot Menu>`. After that format all the hdd, cancel all the possible partitions found and start the installation. The actual OS that is on HDD doesn't really matter if you format the hdd

Answer (score 0):

Since this question already has multiple answers and they all point to the same thing, here's a generic guide to change boot device priority:

1. Get into your BIOS. This is usually done by pressing DEL key repeatedly right after the unit starts. If that does not work, try f2 or TAB key, though you can usually read it as it flashes quickly on the screen.
2. Navigate using your arrow keys. Go to your boot settings/menu.
3. Look for a list of boot devices. This may be inside of a menu option or it may be shown up front.
4. Change boot order. It might be by numbering, or might be tabbing or using arrow keys, or using f5/f6 (Phoenix on laptops). Place flash drive on top of the list, or above the hard disk drive (whichever you prefer). In case of numbering, give the flash drive a higher priority than the hard disk.
5. Boot up and do your thing. Install/Delete OS'es, or just booting from an external device. Your call.

tl;dr. If this does not help, a quick search of your BIOS manufacturer and version should give more info.